# IText "IntelliSense"

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, xmlworker

I need some guidance on achieving the below mentioned objective.

1. Develop something that can run as a scheduled job on Windows Server 2012 that can convert HTML file to PDF. We used to use Omniformat, but after migrating to Windows Server 2012, this is no longer an option as it will just stuck there.
2. I did some POC using iText, look promising except for the following points:
   i.  if the styling did not specify the font-family, IE will render it correctly, however IText will just  print an empty block. This happened to my test case with Arabic and Russian characters.

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Random Text, which I have no idea what are there.<br/>
   
    <span style="font-family: Arabic Typesetting">This works!
    Arabic : &#1587;&#1593;&#1610;&#1583;
    </span>

    <span> This isn't working
    Arabic : &#1587;&#1593;&#1610;&#1583;
    </span>
    <br/>
    <span>
    Russian: &#1057;&#1095;&#1072;&#1089;&#1090;&#1083;&#1080;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;
    </span>
    
    <span style="font-family: MingLiu">
    Simplfied Chinese: &#24555;&#20048;
    </span>
   <br/>
    <span style="font-family: MingLiu">
    Traditional Chinese: &#24555;&#27138;
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I have done so far.

1. I presume I have to have a customized TagProcessor.

   public class MyParaGraph extends ParaGraph
       {

   ```
       @Override
       public List<Element> content(WorkerContext arg0, Tag arg1, String arg2) 
       {
             List<Element> elements = super.content(arg0, arg1,arg2);
             Iterator<Element> eleIter = elements.iterator();
             while(  eleIter.hasNext())
             {
                 Element element = eleIter.next();
                 List<Chunk> chunks = element.getChunks();
                 Iterator<Chunk> chunkIter = chunks.Iterator();

                 while (chunkIter.hasNext())
                 {
                      Chunk chunk = chunkIter.next();
                      for ( char charStr : arg2.toCharArray() )
                      {
                           //Intention is for future, if there is multiple Unicode characteres of different langauge, to create different chunk with differnt Font assigned.  
                           //For now, quite useless loop,

                            //isarabic  
                            if ( (code > 0x600 && code < code < 0x6FF) ||   (code > 0x750 && code < code < 0x77F))    
                            {  
                                 //Pardon me, my dev is not linked to internet, i cant copy and paste so i just define a sub set.
                                 if (chunk.getFont.getBaseFont()==null)
                                 {
                                     //It appear the processor failed to find the font-family style being define, as other tag with font-family define will not be null.
                                       FontFactory.register("C:/Windows/Font/Arabaric Typesetting.ttf");
                                      Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Arabaric TypeSetting");
                                      chunk.setFont(font);  //Its doesnt seems to update it to ask IText ot use Arabaric Typesetting..
                                 }
                            }        
                        }                             
                  }               
             }
       } 
   }
   ```

HTMLPDFConverter.java
Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
TagProcessorFactory factory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
factory.addProcessor(new MyParaGraph(), "p","span", "div");

Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("D:/sample.pdf"));
writer.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
document.open();


HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext (null);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(factory);
CssResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);
Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipleline(doc. writer)));

XMLWorker worker= new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D:/sample.html"), "UTF-8");
doc.close();
}
```

The Arabaric and Russian are not showing in the PDF.
Appreciate any advise. 
Sorry for the mess, I can't copy and paste my POC code from development as they are on different network.
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just set a generic CSS rule on the `<span>` or `<p>` or even the `<body>` tag that iText will ultimately fallback to.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the prompt reply. We did try to add Arial Unicode MS to the cssResolver, the text did show up however the user are not very acceptable with the output.

Comment: Do you have HTML that has both Arabic and Russian in the same file or can you make two different "default CSS" rules, one for each? If they are in the same file, can you modify the HTML in any way to better detect it?

Comment: There are in the same HTML file, and this is just one of the sample test data. There are cases with multiple mixture of multiple languages. Which is why I'm attempting to detect the code page range then to use the best match font as default if it's not already defined. On top of that, if the font are already defined example for Chinese, MingLiu and Microsoft Yahei we are suppose to render it as it is.  regarding your second question, i not sure what you meant. The end user can upload any html the they generate and the quality varies.